# NInject generic common and specific bindings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have one standard generic class and few classes for some type parameters that extend it with specific logic. Specific classes may be in another assemblies so there are different modules. I have guessed to register implemented generic type in addition to universal generic registration and it works, but I don't know why. How NInject resolve `viewer3` in right way, does it take the most specific registration? May be there any problems with singletons? Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new StandardModule(), new BoolModule());

        var viewer1 = kernel.Get<IViewer<string>>();
        var viewer2 = kernel.Get<IViewer<int>>();
        var viewer3 = kernel.Get<IViewer<bool>>();

        viewer1.Show("abc");
        viewer2.Show(123);
        viewer3.Show(true);
    }
}

interface IViewer<T>
{
    void Show(T value);
}

class StandardViewer<T> : IViewer<T>
{
    public void Show(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}

class BoolViewer : IViewer<bool>
{
    public void Show(bool value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value ? "yes!" : "no :(");
    }
}

class StandardModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind(typeof(IViewer<>)).To(typeof(StandardViewer<>)).InSingletonScope();
    }
}

class BoolModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IViewer<bool>>().To<BoolViewer>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

And related question. If I want to add some method to `BoolViewer`, how to use it when resolve, only by cast?

```
var viewer3 = kernel.Get<IViewer<bool>>();
((BoolViewer)viewer3).SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you add multiple bindings for the same type you would use them to inject an array (as per the [multi-injection documentation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Multi-injection)) so no, Ninject doesn't pick the most relevant binding.

You are perhaps confusing that with constructors, where Ninject will apply the rules of [constructor injection](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns):

> - If a constructor has an [Inject] attribute, it is used (but if you    apply the attribute to more than one, Ninject will throw a
>     NotSupportedException at runtime upon detection).
> - If no constructors have an [Inject] attribute, Ninject will select    the one with the most parameters that Ninject understands how    to
>     resolve.
> - If no constructors are defined, Ninject will select the default    parameterless constructor (assuming there is one).

However, what you have in your case is generic bindings. If you look at the [release notes for Ninject 3.0.0](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300) you will see the following feature:

> Added: Open generic bindings can be overriden by closed generics for
>   specific types.

Therefore you have a binding using closed generics for `bool`, which will instantiate your `BoolViewer`. All other requests for an `IViewer<>` will use the open generic binding.